# how to set the background image automatically specially fit the content of the page in angular

Tags: css, angular

[Explanation of what I want to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pfp1.png)

I displayed the problem in the attached picture.
How can I get this result?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue

```css
.myDiv {
  background: url(...) no-repeat;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```